# Recovering deposit from Coinbase Multisig Account

Tags: coinbase.com, multi-signature

I was one of the ones who never received the email about Coinbase discontinuing service of their Multisig Accounts. I tried to use the tool to retrieve my funds and it is stuck on verifying amounts, it never goes further then Step 1. Is there another way to transfer my funds to another bitcoin account (hex/raw transaction)? I have my keys, password, and public address for the account from coinbase, but can't figure out how to get the funds out.

Nonelilian